# Seeking an "easy " way to show that $p(x)=x^6+\cdots+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z_{17}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

As the title suggests, we need to

> Show that $p(x)=x^6+\cdots+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z_{17}}$

We can immediately answer that it is indeed irreducible since it is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_7(x)$, thus it is ireducible over any field $\Bbb{F_p}$, with $p\mod7$ being a generator of the multiplicative group of $\Bbb{Z_7}$.

Alternatively, we can notice that $$x^7-1=(x-1)(x^6+\cdots+x^2+x+1)=(x-1)p(x)$$ and if $r$ is a zero of $p(x)$, it follows that it must have an order of either $1$ or $7$. Since the unit element $1$ is the only one with order one, and we can easily check that it is not a zero, any root-if it exists-must be of order $7$.But since the order of $\Bbb{Z_{17}}$ is $16$ and $7$ does not divide $16$, $p(x)$ has no roots in $\Bbb{Z_{17}}$.

We can also verify that it has no quadratic or cubic factors (we have already shown that no linear factors exist), so it is not irreducible over $\Bbb{Z_{17}}$. (This will involve considering an algebraic extension, of order $2$ and $3$ with $17^2-1$ and $17^3-1$ elements respectively and checking that by Lagrange's Theorem, the order of the element would have to divide $17^2-1=288$ and $17^3-1=4912$, but $7$ does not divide either of the two, thus it has no quadratic or cubic factors).

What I am looking for is something more trivial, if such a solution exists.

Comment: Your alternative only shows that the polyn9mial has no root, not that it is irreducible.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You mean that even if we show that no quadratic or cubic factors exist via the approach sketched, we are not done? Of course the alternative was never fully developed and I frankly can't remember if I did it on pen and paper after all this time...

Answer (score 2):

Show that $p(x)$ is a factor of $x^{17^6}-x$ and relatively prime to $x^{17^3}-x$ and $x^{17^2}-x$.

To do so, note that $p(x)(x-1)=x^{7}-1$. So $x^{17^2}-x=(x^7-1)q(x)+x^{2}-x$ for some $q(x)$. Similarly, note that $x^{17^3}-x=(x^7-1)r(x)+x^6-x$.

So you just need to show that $p(x)$ is relatively prim to $x^2-x$ and $x^6-x$. This is easy to do.

Finally, $x^{17^6}-x$ is actually divisible by $x^7-1$ since $17^6-1$ is divisible by $7$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer+1! It is certainly shorter than the second approach, though I feel it still involves non-trivial means to be honest..